# Does Google Location Services return old locations?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location-services

I am trying to track my location every 2 mins to check the distance from me to my house.  However the results I have been getting have been odd.  When I would travel about 700 meters away (to another building) and stay there for 2 hours the results would say that I was always within 40 meters of my home.  They would change but the distance never got bigger than that.

```
  private void locationSetup(){
    int interval = 120000;
    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(interval)        // 2 mins, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(10000); // 10 seconds, in milliseconds

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Because it thinks I am close to my house rather than all over the place I am assuming that it is not an accuracy issue but a cache issue, but I have been unable to find anything related to that online.

What could be causing this?

---

Here is some logs to show it in action.  the distance is distance from my home, at the time I was 700 meters from home.

```
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1885: 04:12 - Distance: 772.6915 - Accuracy: 185.759 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1886: 04:13 - Distance: 772.6915 - Accuracy: 529.961 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1887: 04:14 - Distance: 707.7302 - Accuracy: 107.0 - Proivder: gps
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1888: 04:14 - Distance: 707.7302 - Accuracy: 107.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1889: 04:15 - Distance: 696.931 - Accuracy: 60.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1890: 04:16 - Distance: 670.4543 - Accuracy: 131.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1891: 04:18 - Distance: 704.91797 - Accuracy: 92.0 - Proivder: gps
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1892: 04:18 - Distance: 704.9204 - Accuracy: 92.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1893: 04:18 - Distance: 765.78534 - Accuracy: 131.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1894: 04:19 - Distance: 772.657 - Accuracy: 232.21 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1895: 04:21 - Distance: 9.328314 - Accuracy: 25.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1896: 04:21 - Distance: 693.4839 - Accuracy: 110.0 - Proivder: gps
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1897: 04:23 - Distance: 693.0056 - Accuracy: 676.849 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1898: 04:23 - Distance: 679.2539 - Accuracy: 148.0 - Proivder: gps
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1899: 04:23 - Distance: 679.25574 - Accuracy: 148.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1900: 04:23 - Distance: 686.7772 - Accuracy: 43.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1901: 04:24 - Distance: 707.85034 - Accuracy: 55.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1902: 04:25 - Distance: 707.85034 - Accuracy: 333.62 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1903: 04:25 - Distance: 683.21533 - Accuracy: 88.0 - Proivder: gps
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1904: 04:25 - Distance: 683.21783 - Accuracy: 88.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1905: 04:27 - Distance: 9.328314 - Accuracy: 25.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1906: 04:28 - Distance: 748.212 - Accuracy: 124.0 - Proivder: gps
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1907: 04:28 - Distance: 748.21686 - Accuracy: 124.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1908: 04:29 - Distance: 743.08234 - Accuracy: 709.707 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1909: 04:30 - Distance: 743.1258 - Accuracy: 75.0 - Proivder: gps
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1910: 04:30 - Distance: 743.1303 - Accuracy: 75.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1911: 04:32 - Distance: 742.66644 - Accuracy: 611.683 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1912: 04:32 - Distance: 741.3365 - Accuracy: 147.0 - Proivder: gps
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1913: 04:32 - Distance: 741.33484 - Accuracy: 147.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1914: 04:32 - Distance: 741.22455 - Accuracy: 143.0 - Proivder: fused
11-29 17:40:06.106 20319-20319/farmcloud.gpstest I/1915: 04:34 - Distance: 741.22455 - Accuracy: 556.811 - Proivder: fused
```

Comment: Do you have an account and API key with Google? If you are using the free one you could be going over the limits which are set per sec, min, hour etc.

Comment: No, none of my code is related to an API Key.

Comment: Do you have access fine location in your manifest? Also, what are your device's location settings set to?

Comment: Yes, fine location is the the manifest.  I have one device set on high accuracy and another using android 4.1 so there is no options available.  Both have same results.