# How to get the correct location despite the android location bugs

Tags: android, geolocation

**Goal:** to record the users location every minute.

**Attempt 1:** Google Location Services API

I found this method gave inaccurate results.  I would leave a location and instead of saying I was miles away from home it would say I was about 10 meters away.  Sometimes it would correct itself after 10 mins or so, sometimes it would take a 3 or more hours.

```
public class timesheetService extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
 private void locationSetup(){
    int interval = 120000;
    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(interval)        // 2 mins, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(10000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
   Log.i("location", String.valueOf(location));
}
```

More detail can be found in my unanswered question about it: [Does Google Location Services return old locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634547/does-google-location-services-return-old-locations)

**Attempt 2:** Built-in location APIs

This method works perfectly with the exception of the major bug on newer devices of not listening for location changes until the device has been restarted.  As described here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707

```
  private LocationManager locationManager;

public void getLocation2() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            60 * 1000,//seconds * milliseconds
            0, // distance (meters)
            LListener);
}
android.location.LocationListener LListener = new android.location.LocationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("classic", String.valueOf(location));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.i("status", String.valueOf(status));
    }


};
```

---

So how do people do it?  I know it must be possible but I have been stuck on this problem for weeks and I don't understand why either method doesn't work properly.

Comment: I've used the fused and native location api. Both works fine. Ate you sure you followed every step of this doc https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates ? For example you should requestLocationUpdates() in onConnected () of api client.

Comment: I have posted all the applicable code, let me know if anything stands out to you.  From what I can tell it is no different from the tutorial as I basically copied it into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee that you'll be able to get a Location every minute. The best you could achieve would be to register a [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)) with the LocationManager system service. You can set the minDistance parameter to a very low value such as 10m to get very regular updates.

This should all be done in a background thread, and will impact battery life. If you don't need to know the location regularly with accuracy in your app, using something like Google Play Services to get the last known location is a good trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your previous question as linked:

Did you ensure to register for location updates like so?

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

If not, your code is likely receiving the last known location once, then not requesting any more updates. Take a look at the code snippets here: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

If you do have the aforementioned code, then ensure your Location settings are set to High Accuracy on your device and you have the appropriate Manifest permissions (coarse and fine accuracy), then post your code here.

Both Location APIs can be finnicky but they are definitely not bugged to the extent you've described. I have tried both in an application I'm creating and have been consistently able to get accurate results.

Comment: Yes, I have done that.  It still receives updates every minute and they are different each time, they just happen to be around the same area instead of where I have move to.  I'll update the question to include the code.